# Problema no POST da chave estrangeira usando o ecossistema Spring (API REST)

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Eu não estou conseguindo realizar o `POST` em `Usuario` porque ele possui chaves estrangeiras.

**Erro devolvido pelo PostMan**:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-06-30T15:03:40.631+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `br.com.api.feiraqui.model.Usuario` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `br.com.api.feiraqui.model.Usuario` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:391)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:185)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `br.com.api.feiraqui.model.Usuario` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:638)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:210)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:186)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3682)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:380)\r\n\t... 51 more\r\n",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `br.com.api.feiraqui.model.Usuario` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `br.com.api.feiraqui.model.Usuario` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
    "path": "/usuario/cadastro"
}
```

**Usuario** (Model):

```
package br.com.api.feiraqui.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "nome_completo", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String nome_completo;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "rg_numero", length = 9, nullable = false)
    private long rg_numero;

    @Column(name = "rg_orgao_emissor", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private String rg_orgao_emissor;

    @Column(name = "cpf", length = 11, nullable = false)
    private long cpf;

    @Column(name = "senha", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String senha;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Endereco.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_endereco", nullable = false)
    private long id_endereco;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Telefone.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_telefone", nullable = false)
    private long id_telefone;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome_completo() {
        return nome_completo;
    }

    public void setNome_completo(String nome_completo) {
        this.nome_completo = nome_completo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getRg_numero() {
        return rg_numero;
    }

    public void setRg_numero(long rg_numero) {
        this.rg_numero = rg_numero;
    }

    public String getRg_orgao_emissor() {
        return rg_orgao_emissor;
    }

    public void setRg_orgao_emissor(String rg_orgao_emissor) {
        this.rg_orgao_emissor = rg_orgao_emissor;
    }

    public long getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(long cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public long getId_endereco() {
        return id_endereco;
    }

    public long getId_telefone() {
        return id_telefone;
    }

}
```

**UsuarioController**:

```
package br.com.api.feiraqui.controller;

import br.com.api.feiraqui.DAO.IUsuario;
import br.com.api.feiraqui.model.Usuario;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuario dao;

    @GetMapping("/lista")
    public List<Usuario> listaUsuarios (){
        return (List<Usuario>) dao.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/cadastro")
    public Usuario cadastrarUsuario (@RequestBody Usuario usuario){
        Usuario usuarioNovo = dao.save(usuario);
        return usuarioNovo;
    }
}
```

Além desses, existe o **IUsuario** (DAO), e os Model, DAO e Controller de **Endereco** e **Telefone**.

É o seguinte, no meu banco de dados existe as chaves estrangeiras `id_endereco` e `id_telefone` que são inteiros. Porém, no momento de declarar elas no Model eu tranformei em objetos (`Endereco endereco` e `Telefone telefone`).
Para o `GET` funciona perfeitamente, até porque tudo da entidade estrangeira vem junto, mas quando eu tento fazer o `POST` ele devolve esse erro e, imagino eu, ele se refere a tipagem.

O que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa pratica é vc utilizar um **DTO** para receber os dados no seu endpoint e depois transformar esse **DTO** na **Entity** que deseja.
É bem comum ter problemas na hora de **serializar** ou **deserializar** quando usa diretamente a **Entity**.

O **DTO** seria uma classe igual a da **Entity**, entretanto sem as anotações de configuração.

Answer (score 0):

O erro tem a ver com a renderização do objeto que você enviou, não é relacionado ao banco de dados. No caso você está enviando um **array** de **Usuários**, que é representado pelos colchetes `[]`, e seu endpoint está aguardando um **único** usuário.

Array (errado):

```
[
  {
    "nome_completo":"Roberto",
    //restante dos campos
  }
]
```

Correto:

```
{
  "nome_completo":"Roberto",
  //restante dos campos
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).